# Trying to evaluate $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-e^{2k\pi i/n})$ for my complex analysis homework

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For my complex analysis homework, I am trying to show that the integral of the real function $1/(1+x^n)$, for integer $n\ge2$, along the positive real line is
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^n} = \frac{\pi}{n\sin(\pi/n)}.$$
The suggested approach is to consider the contour integral
$$\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz = \int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{1+z^n},$$
where $\gamma$ is a contour construced such that it traverses all of the positive real line, but only a single simple pole is included. So I started out by factoring the polynomial in the denominator, which has (distinct) roots $\omega_k=\exp(i[\pi+2k\pi]/n)$, so that $1+z^n=(z-\omega_0)(z-\omega_1)\cdots(z-\omega_{n-1})$. Using this, I attempt to find the residue at $z=\omega_0$ (which is the single pole included in $\gamma$ by construction) by
$$\text{Res}_{\omega_0}f=\lim_{z\rightarrow\omega_0}\frac{1}{(z-\omega_0)\cdots(z-\omega_{n-1})}(z-\omega_0)= \frac{1}{(\omega_0-\omega_1)\cdots(\omega_0-\omega_{n-1})}.$$

I have found that for every $(\omega_0-\omega_k)=\exp(i\pi/n)-\exp(i\pi/n+2k\pi i/n)$, I can extract an $\omega_0$ from the $\omega_k$, yielding $(\omega_0-\omega_k)=\exp(i\pi/n)[1-\exp(2k\pi i/n)]$ such that we are left with
$$\text{Res}_{\omega_0}f=\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} e^{i\pi/n}[1-e^{2k\pi i/n}]}=\frac{1}{e^{i\pi(n-1)/n}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(1 - e^{2k\pi i /n}\right)}.$$

Now, since I know the final answer, I strongly believe that 
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-e^{2k\pi i/n} )=n,$$
but I am having a very hard time trying to evaluate this product. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, you may let $x^n \mapsto x$ and use a keyhole contour instead.

Comment: @M.N.C.E. I don't really understand what you mean by just _letting_ $x^n\mapsto x$?

Comment: \begin{align}
\int^\infty_0\frac{{\rm d}x}{1+x^n}
=&\frac{1}{n}\int^\infty_0\frac{x^{\frac{1-n}{n}}}{1+x}{\rm d}x
\end{align}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$z^n - 1 = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(z - e^{2k\pi i/n})$, so we have

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(z - e^{2k\pi i/n}) = \dfrac{z^n - 1}{z-1}, \forall z \neq 1$$

Remark $\dfrac{z^n - 1}{z-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^k$, now take limit $z\to 1$

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!