# Closed form of product of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm stuck in a proof where I want to get a closed form of something. This is the last thing I need to complete my proof:

Apparently for small $n\geq2$, the product $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-\exp(\frac{2ki\pi}{n}))=n$. 
How can i show it for all $n\geq2$?

It does not seem too hard to show, so any hints are welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: **Hint:** The $n^{th}$ roots of unity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The roots of the polynomial

$$f(z) = z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}+\cdots+z^2+z+1 = \frac{z^n-1}{z-1} $$

are $z_k = e^{i 2 \pi k/n}$ for $k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$.  Thus,

$$f(z) = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \left ( z-e^{i 2 \pi k/n}\right ) $$

and therefore

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \left ( 1-e^{i 2 \pi k/n}\right ) = f(1) = n$$

Comment: OP asked for a hint, this seems to be a full exposition.

Comment: "...so any hints are welcome."  Pretty vague to me.  In any case, I left a lot of gaps.

Comment: I guess the OP did leave gaps but your answer seems to leave none :-)

Comment: @r9m: depends on how much common sense one has.

Comment: Yes indeed ....

Comment: Very nicely done, ***+1***!

Comment: The polynomial expression for $f(z)$ is defined for any $z$, while the right hand side blows up at $z=1$. How can they be equal?

Comment: @MaxisJaisi: It's equal in a limiting sense as $z \to 1^-$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

The expression $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}x-\mathbb{e}^{\frac{2\mathbb{i}k\pi}{n}}$  can be expanded as a polynomial (which then allows you to evaluate this sum for $1$ or any other number).

Comment: It's the factorization of a certain polynomial, not the other way round.

Comment: Indeed, used the wrong word (this polynomial is a "well-known").

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$1-e^{i\alpha}=1-\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha=2\sin^2\frac{\alpha}2+2i\sin\frac{\alpha}2\cos\frac{\alpha}2=2\sin\frac{\alpha}2e^{i\alpha/2}.$$

Comment: How do we deal with the half angle sines next ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Identities_without_variables (but this was probably established from the formula in your question :-) )

Comment: :-) I'd prefer to derive the wiki result from the OP than doing the other way :)