# Roots of unity polynomial

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Let $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$.

Prove that $\Pi_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-\omega^k)=n.$

So far, I've tried brute-forcing it by expanding out the product, but it ended up getting too messy--and now I'm clueless as to how to proceed. I know the answer has to be fairly straightforward, but it's pretty late at night. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to proceed? Have you tried anything? It is usually best **not** to copy a problem out of your problem list here... (One particular problem with your post is that you do not give any indication at all about what you know, and therefore it is very easy for someone to come and write an answer which is waaay over your head, and similar phenomena)

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit what I've tried into the post.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/806679/589.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$w^k$ for $k\in\text{{1,2,...n}}$ are roots of $z^n=1$

or, $z^n-1 \equiv(z-1)(z-w)(z-w^2)...(z-w^{\text{n-1}})$

also, $$(z-w)(z-w^2)...(z-w^{\text{n-1}})=\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}=(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}+...+1)$$

plugging $z=1$

$(1-w)(1-w^2)...(1-w^{\text{n-1}})=(1+1...+1)=n$

Comment: Very well done indeed, ***plus one!***

Comment: @RobertLewis thank u very much :)

Comment: And you are more than welcome!  Cheers!

Comment: Of course, the correct answer, I just think the "or" on second line is not thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: @orangeskid edit it however u see fit :)